# Как привязать горячии клавиши в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии клавиш Ctrl+H выполнялась функция.

Comment: посмотрите метод bind

Answer (score 1):

Привязать функцию на нажатие `Ctrl-H` можно так:

```py
tk.bind('<Control-h>', func)
```

`tk` - `tkinter.Tk()`

`func` - функция, вызывающаяся при нажатии `Ctrl-H`. Должна принимать только аргумент `event`, например:

```py
def func(event):
    # Какие-то действия
```

А что делать, если `func` должна принимать ещё аргументы, например так:

```py
def func(event, a):
    print(a + 1)
```

Тут есть два способа:

1. Написать обертку, которая будет вызывать `func` с нужным аргументом:

```py
def wrapper(event):
    func(event, a)
```

И привязать её так:

```py
tk.bind('<Control-h>', wrapper)
```

2. Использовать ключевое слово `lambda` так:

```py
tk.bind('<Control-h>', lambda: func(a))
```

(По сути это сокращенный вариант 1)